# python: test for existence of any of multiple strings in a text field to set new column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

have been trying for a good while now and cannot find an answer online, so... I'm sure someone can help.

I have a dataframe with a column that contains descriptive text, e.g.
`"BALANCE SHRINKER - CORE"`
Each row has a different text value.

I need to check for the existence of any of multiple words:
`['LOB','LIFE','SHRINKER']` say.
And from the result (True/False), create a new column set to 999 if any phrase is found in the text column being searched, or set to 0 otherwise.

I have tried this kind of approach but nothing works for me:
`df['rule1'] = 999 if any(x in df['textcolumn'].str for x in ['LOB','LIFE','SHRINKER']) else 0`

I've tried `.find()` and `.contains()` but to no avail.

So, I'm sure someone can advise!

Thanks for looking.
DT

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info about the failures?  Are you getting error messages or incorrect values?
You might also try the "pd.DataFrame.apply()" method described here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check if each row of 'textcolumn' contains any of the words, producing a boolean Series.  Then  use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html?highlight=map%20series#pandas.Series.map) to map the True values to 900, and the False values to 0.

```
# list of words to find in 'textcolumn'
words = ['LOB','LIFE','SHRINKER']
# regex pattern to search in 'textcolumn'
# '|' stands for OR. Read pat as "match 'LOB' OR 'LIFE' OR 'SHRINKER'"
pat = "|".join(words)

df['rule1'] = df['textcolumn'].str.contains(pat).map({True: 999, False: 0})
```

Another option is to use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np

words = ['LOB','LIFE','SHRINKER']
pat = "|".join(words)

df['rule1'] = np.where(df['textcolumn'].str.contains(pat), 999, 0)
```

Comment: Top man, works perfectly, much appreciated !

Comment: @DanielThomas no problem, happy to help! If it solves your issue, please mark the answer as accepted until you possibly get another answer that you prefer.

Comment: yes i had already  :)

Comment: @DanielThomas I think you just upvoted it ;) In case you don't know,  to accept the answer you have to click the [“checkmark” button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) underneath the vote buttons.  Happy coding!

Comment: done, thnx for the pointer :)